# Maximum number of tuples permited in a findAll function of symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a database with a table that has more than *5000 tuples*, and when i do the `findAll()` in the *Symfony Controller* i get error **500**.

So i'm looking for the maximum number of tuples that **Doctrine** can handle with and if this number can be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Most of Doctrine's limits are resource constraints, especially RAM. Please take a look at it's batch [processing](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html) for workawords. Matters are made worse when you are doing several joins in big queries especially because of hydration, you can read more about it from a core dev [here](https://ocramius.github.io/blog/doctrine-orm-optimization-hydration/). Therefore, it really isn't right to say that doctrine has a limit per say, a lot depends on the schema and query, for further assistance could you share your schema, query and php version and settings for max_execution, and memory limit. Also consider enabling caches if you haven't.